# Altbeacon Android, I need wake up app only If device enter in region

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I am making an application, I need to wake up the app ( previously app is closed or background).
Well, my app works half-way fine .... When the device is inside region, the app wake up ... but when the device is out of the region ... wake up too ...  I don´t know if is posibble only wake up with didEnterRegion.
The problem is  when the device is out of the region , the app wake up every times...I mean, wake up app, I close app manually.. wake up... I close app manually...always with message exit region...

On the other hand.. I get didEnterRegion(), and just after..didExitRegion...sometimes I get didExitRegion but I´m in region...I work with beacon with protocol IBeacon and my device is Android 6

My code is:

```
public class Activity extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier,BeaconConsumer,RangeNotifier {..
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "App started up");
        manager.setAndroidLScanningDisabled(true);
        manager.bind(this);
    }

  @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Beacon Service Connected");
        manager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(3000l);
        manager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(3000l);
        manager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(3000l);
        manager.setForegroundScanPeriod(3000l);
        manager.setDebug(true);
        region = new Region("com.example.backgroundRegion",
                Identifier.parse("MY UUID"), null, null);

    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
    manager.getBeaconParsers().add(
            new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));

    manager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
            "make my operations...."
        }

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(Region region) {

        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
        }

    });
    manager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion
(Collection<Beacon> collection, Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "didRangeBeaconsInRegion");
        }
    });

    try {
        manager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
        manager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Remote Exception Error: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {

        Log.i(TAG, "BootstrapNotifier didEnterRegion");
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
        Log.i(TAG, "BootstrapNotifier didExitRegion");
    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {

        Log.i(TAG, "BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion");
    }

    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> collection, Region region) {

    }
```

---

NEW CODE

---

```
public class Activity extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier,RangeNotifier {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "App started up");
     manager=BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(getApplicationContext());
        backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
        manager.setAndroidLScanningDisabled(true);
        manager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1000l);
        manager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(1000l);
        manager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(1000l);
        manager.setForegroundScanPeriod(1000l);
        manager.setDebug(true);
        region = new Region("com.example.backgroundRegion",
                Identifier.parse("MY UUID"), null, null);
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);

        manager.getBeaconParsers().add(
                new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
        manager.addRangeNotifier(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {

        Log.i(TAG, "BootstrapNotifier didEnterRegion");
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {

        Log.i(TAG, "BootstrapNotifier didExitRegion");

    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {

        Log.i(TAG, "BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion"+state);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> collection, Region region) {
        Log.i(TAG, " BootstrapNotifier didRangeBeaconsInRegion");

    }
}
```

And this is my log

```
I/.Activity: App started up
12-22 12:30:49.046 11591-11591/com.myapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.
11591-11591/com.myapp I/BeaconService: beaconService version 2.9.2 is starting up
 W/BluetoothCrashResolver: Can't read macs from BluetoothCrashResolverState.txt
/com.myapp I/CycledLeScanner: This Android 5.0, but L scanning is disabled. We are using old scanning APIs
/com.myapp W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
/com.myapp W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
/com.myapp I/BeaconService: starting with intent Intent { cmp=com.myapp/org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService }
/com.myapp I/BeaconService: binding
/com.myapp I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 52af4d2, I8366cd0437
                          Build Date                       : 10/20/15
                          OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.05.13.02
                          Local Branch                     : M14
                          Remote Branch                    : 
                          Remote Branch                    : 
                          Reconstruct Branch               : 
/com.myapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
/com.myapp I/.IbeaconActivity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion0
/com.myapp I/BeaconService: start monitoring received
12-22 11:40:29.971 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion0
12-22 11:40:29.971 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didExitRegion
12-22 11:40:47.050 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion1
12-22 11:40:47.050 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didEnterRegion
12-22 11:41:17.949 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion0
12-22 11:41:17.951 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didExitRegion
12-22 11:41:35.074 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion1
12-22 11:41:35.075 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didEnterRegion
12-22 11:42:07.985 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion0
12-22 11:42:07.985 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didExitRegion
12-22 11:42:23.094 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion1
12-22 11:42:23.097 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didEnterRegion
12-22 11:42:51.963 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion0
12-22 11:42:51.964 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didExitRegion
12-22 11:43:09.041 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion1
12-22 11:43:09.041 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didEnterRegion
12-22 11:43:39.951 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion0
12-22 11:43:39.953 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didExitRegion
12-22 11:43:57.085 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion1
12-22 11:43:57.085 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didEnterRegion
12-22 11:44:29.978 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion0
12-22 11:44:29.982 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didExitRegion
12-22 11:44:45.082 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion1
12-22 11:44:45.082 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didEnterRegion
12-22 11:45:17.945 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion0
12-22 11:45:17.945 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didExitRegion
12-22 11:45:33.067 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion1
12-22 11:45:33.067 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didEnterRegion
12-22 11:46:01.964 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion0
12-22 11:46:01.964 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didExitRegion
12-22 11:46:19.028 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion1
12-22 11:46:19.028 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didEnterRegion
12-22 11:46:49.960 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion0
12-22 11:46:49.963 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didExitRegion
12-22 11:47:07.035 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion1
12-22 11:47:07.035 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didEnterRegion
12-22 11:47:37.966 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion0
12-22 11:47:37.966 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didExitRegion
12-22 11:47:55.057 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion1
12-22 11:47:55.057 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didEnterRegion
12-22 11:48:27.955 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion0
12-22 11:48:27.956 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didExitRegion
12-22 11:48:40.995 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion1
12-22 11:48:40.996 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didEnterRegion
12-22 11:49:11.974 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion0
12-22 11:49:11.977 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didExitRegion
12-22 11:49:29.048 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion1
12-22 11:49:29.048 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didEnterRegion
12-22 11:50:01.955 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion0
12-22 11:50:01.955 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didExitRegion
12-22 11:50:17.075 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion1
12-22 11:50:17.076 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didEnterRegion
12-22 11:50:49.952 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion0
12-22 11:50:49.959 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didExitRegion
12-22 11:51:05.098 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion1
12-22 11:51:05.098 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didEnterRegion
12-22 11:51:33.963 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion0
12-22 11:51:33.964 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didExitRegion
12-22 11:51:51.045 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion1
12-22 11:51:51.046 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didEnterRegion
12-22 11:52:21.966 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion0
12-22 11:52:21.966 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didExitRegion
12-22 11:52:39.054 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion1
12-22 11:52:39.056 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didEnterRegion
12-22 11:53:11.971 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion0
12-22 11:53:11.971 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didExitRegion
12-22 11:53:27.067 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion1
12-22 11:53:27.068 Activity: BootstrapNotifier didEnterRegion
```

this is your debug log

```
D/BeaconParser: Ignoring pdu type 01
12-22 11:55:37.810 12502-12653/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Processing pdu type FF: 02011a07ff4c0010020100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 10
12-22 11:55:37.811 12502-12653/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 02011a07ff4c0010020100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
12-22 11:55:37.811 12502-12653/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Ignoring pdu type 01
12-22 11:55:37.814 12502-12653/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Processing pdu type FF: 02011a07ff4c0010020100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 10
12-22 11:55:37.814 12502-12653/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 4c 00 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 02011a07ff4c0010020100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
12-22 11:55:37.923 12502-12502/com.myapp D/CycledLeScanner: Done with scan cycle
12-22 11:55:37.926 12502-12502/com.myapp D/CycledLeScanner: stopping bluetooth le scan
12-22 11:55:37.926 12502-12533/com.myapp D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-22 11:55:37.926 12502-12502/com.myapp D/CycledLeScanner: Normalizing between scan period from 1000 to 987
12-22 11:55:37.927 12502-12502/com.myapp D/CycledLeScannerForJellyBeanMr2: Waiting to start next Bluetooth scan for another 987 milliseconds
12-22 11:55:37.930 12502-12533/com.myapp D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-22 11:55:38.915 12502-12502/com.myapp D/CycledLeScanner: starting a new scan cycle
12-22 11:55:38.921 12502-12502/com.myapp D/CycledLeScanner: starting a new bluetooth le scan
12-22 11:55:38.923 12502-12533/com.myapp D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-22 11:55:38.923 12502-12502/com.myapp D/CycledLeScanner: Waiting to stop scan cycle for another 1000 milliseconds
12-22 11:55:38.924 12502-12502/com.myapp D/CycledLeScanner: Scan started
12-22 11:55:38.927 12502-12533/com.myapp D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-22 11:55:38.935 12502-20381/com.myapp D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=10
12-22 11:55:39.056 12502-12502/com.myapp D/CycledLeScannerForJellyBeanMr2: got record
12-22 11:55:39.057 12502-12661/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Ignoring pdu type 01
12-22 11:55:39.058 12502-12661/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Processing pdu type FF: 02011b0bff4c0009060305c0a801660000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 14
12-22 11:55:39.059 12502-12661/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 02011b0bff4c0009060305c0a801660000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
12-22 11:55:39.059 12502-12661/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Ignoring pdu type 01
12-22 11:55:39.060 12502-12661/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Processing pdu type FF: 02011b0bff4c0009060305c0a801660000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 14
12-22 11:55:39.060 12502-12661/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 4c 00 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 02011b0bff4c0009060305c0a801660000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
12-22 11:55:39.063 12502-12502/com.myapp D/CycledLeScannerForJellyBeanMr2: got record
12-22 11:55:39.064 12502-12660/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Ignoring pdu type 01
12-22 11:55:39.065 12502-12660/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Ignoring pdu type 03
12-22 11:55:39.065 12502-12660/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: No PDUs to process in this packet.
12-22 11:55:39.065 12502-12660/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Ignoring pdu type 01
12-22 11:55:39.066 12502-12660/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Ignoring pdu type 03
12-22 11:55:39.066 12502-12660/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: No PDUs to process in this packet.
12-22 11:55:39.088 12502-12502/com.myapp D/CycledLeScannerForJellyBeanMr2: got record
12-22 11:55:39.089 12502-12658/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Ignoring pdu type 01
12-22 11:55:39.090 12502-12658/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Processing pdu type FF: 02011a07ff4c0010020100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 10
12-22 11:55:39.091 12502-12658/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 02011a07ff4c0010020100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
12-22 11:55:39.091 12502-12658/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Ignoring pdu type 01
12-22 11:55:39.091 12502-12658/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Processing pdu type FF: 02011a07ff4c0010020100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 10
12-22 11:55:39.092 12502-12658/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 4c 00 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 02011a07ff4c0010020100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
12-22 11:55:39.240 12502-12502/com.myapp D/CycledLeScannerForJellyBeanMr2: got record
12-22 11:55:39.241 12502-12659/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Ignoring pdu type 01
12-22 11:55:39.243 12502-12659/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Processing pdu type FF: 02011b0bff4c0009060305c0a801660000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 14
12-22 11:55:39.243 12502-12659/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 02011b0bff4c0009060305c0a801660000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
12-22 11:55:39.244 12502-12659/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Ignoring pdu type 01
12-22 11:55:39.244 12502-12659/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Processing pdu type FF: 02011b0bff4c0009060305c0a801660000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 14
12-22 11:55:39.245 12502-12659/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 4c 00 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 02011b0bff4c0009060305c0a801660000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
12-22 11:55:39.273 12502-12502/com.myapp D/CycledLeScannerForJellyBeanMr2: got record
12-22 11:55:39.274 12502-12653/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Ignoring pdu type 01
12-22 11:55:39.276 12502-12653/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Processing pdu type FF: 02011a07ff4c0010020100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 10
12-22 11:55:39.277 12502-12653/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 02011a07ff4c0010020100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
12-22 11:55:39.277 12502-12653/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Ignoring pdu type 01
12-22 11:55:39.278 12502-12653/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: Processing pdu type FF: 02011a07ff4c0010020100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 10
12-22 11:55:39.279 12502-12653/com.myapp D/BeaconParser: This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 4c 00 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 02011a07ff4c0010020100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: If you run the app in the foreground, do you also get entry/exit callbacks repeatedly when the beacon is always in the vicinity?

Comment: Yes @ davidgyoung... and now I´m hide all code that references the BeaconConsumer interface, and the didRangeBeaconsInRegion method is never called.
I edited my question with the new code and with my registration

Comment: The log indicates that Bluetooth devices are being detected successfully,  but no iBeacon packets are present.  The simplest explanation is that your beacon is not advertising frequently enough.  Some less expensive beacons only advertise every 10 seconds or so to save battery.  You may want to see if you can increase the advertising rate.

Comment: Hi @davidgyoung, I don´t know why.... but only If implement BeaconConsumer interface didRangeBeaconsInRegion is called....I'm going to write to the company that created the beacon to check the device. When I got the beacon, the developers said me... the device emit every 100 milliseconds, which is what apple demands to meet the Ibeacon protocol

Comment: The logs show 2.5 seconds without a single iBeacon packet detected by Android.

Comment: Sorry for the delay @ davidgyoung, I was out by christmas. You are right , we have problem with the beacon. But why If only implement BootstrapNotifier never call didRangeBeaconsInRegion and If I implement BeaconConsumer  didRangeBeaconsInRegion is called? Maybe is problem of my beacon??? thanks and happy new  year

Comment: The new code is missing a call to start ranging.  You can put it in the didDetermineStateForRegion method.

Comment: argg stupid mistake... thanks so much for your time @davidgyoung

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unusual to make a class implement both the BeaconConsumer and BootstrapNotifier interfaces simultaneously.  This may not be causing the problem you are seeing, but it is not a widely tested configuration that may be contributing to it.

I would modify the code so it looks like below and see if the problem continues:

```
public class Activity extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier,RangeNotifier {..
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i(TAG, "App started up");
    manager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    manager.setAndroidLScanningDisabled(true);
    manager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(3000l);
    manager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(3000l);
    manager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(3000l);
    manager.setForegroundScanPeriod(3000l);
    manager.setDebug(true);
    region = new Region("com.example.backgroundRegion",
            Identifier.parse("MY UUID"), null, null);

    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
    manager.getBeaconParsers().add(
        new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    manager.addRangeNotifier(this);
  }


  @Override
  public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    Log.i(TAG, "BootstrapNotifier didEnterRegion");
  }

  @Override
  public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    Log.i(TAG, "BootstrapNotifier didExitRegion");
  }

  @Override
  public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {
    Log.i(TAG, "BootstrapNotifier didDetermineStateForRegion");
    try {
        manager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Remote Exception Error: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> collection, Region region) {
        Log.i(TAG, "didRangeBeaconsInRegion");
  }
```

Comment: Hi @davidgyoung, I implement both the BeaconConsumer and BootstrapNotifier interfaces  because If only implement BootstrapNotifier, never call  didRangeBeaconsInRegion method...